# Android array as global variable

Tags: android, arrays, global-variables

I know how to pass a variable from one activity to another using global variables.

e.g.
In one.java:

```
   GlobalVars.setColour(0);
```

In two.java:

```
 if (GlobalVars.getColour() == 0) ...
```

GlobalVariables.java:

```
 private static int colour2;

    public static int getColour() {
        return colour2;
    }

    public static void setColour(int colour) {
        colour2 = colour;
    }
```

What if i have an array in one.java and i need it in another class?

```
 ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();
```

myArr is uploaded with contacts from the phone book of the phone, so it is dynamic. I need it to upload a ListView with its elements in a custom dialog class. How to pass it to another activity/dialog?

Comment: Have you considered using a singleton pattern or passing the array as a intent extra?

Comment: Global variables aren't a strategy for passing variables around. Use `Intents` and extras like @matsjoe suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you have chosen (creating a static instance) WILL work for an object like `ArrayList` in the same fashion as you did with the primitive (this is creating a Singleton).

However, in most cases creating static fields just to pass data between Activities is definitely not recommended.  Both primitive data and `ArrayList<String>` can be passed as extras in the Intent you use to start another Activity.

```
private ArrayList<String> mArray;
private String mString;
private int mValue;

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("arrayListExtra", mArray);
intent.putExtra("stringExtra", mString);
intent.putExtra("intExtra", mValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

All of these data types (and more) can be seamlessly passed in an `Intent`.  Then, you can access them on the other side as follows:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> array = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("arrayListExtra");
String string = intent.getStringExtra("stringExtra");
int value = intent.getIntExtra("intExtra", 0);
```

If you are passing the data to a Dialog then you can call a setter method and pass anything you want without worrying about the boundaries that exist between Activities.  For instance, with a custom Dialog implement a method in your dialog so you can set the value before displaying it.

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {
    private ArrayList<String> mItems;

    //All other methods of the dialog here

    public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }
}
```

Then, in whichever method of your Activity you plan to create and show the Dialog do

```
//theArray is your ArrayList<String> with data.
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.setItems(theArray);
dialog.show();
```

Notice that this is how you would pass a list of items to an AlertDialog for display.  These dialogs also have methods like `setItems()` to pass data in before showing it.  If you're Activity manages the dialog for you (you're calling `showDialog()` from the Activity), call the setter in `onCreateDialog()` or `onPrepareDialog()`...whichever is more appropriate.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I am sending the array to a dialog class, not an activity. I guess this is the reason why the app results in crash. How can is use your code in this case?

Comment: Good to know, updated with information about Dialogs.  A Dialog is just a member of your Activity, so you can pass it anything you like using setter methods either customized by you or already present in classes like AlertDialog.

Comment: AlertDialog solved my problem, however i want to use my customdialog with my layout. dialog.setItems(theArray); is not working even if "theArray" is a String or a CharSequence (i converted the string arraylist into charsequence). Error msg: "The method setItems(ArrayList<String>) is undefined for the type MyDialog"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sent data from one `Activity` to another, you should use an `Intent`. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), CollegeDetails.class);
intent.putExtra("key", objectvalue);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What if i am using a dialog class not an acitivy? I tried it out, result is crash.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make an instance of the class you want to use in the other class then access the array.

```
Public Class MyClass 
{
  public ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>(); 
}

Public Class MyClassTwo
{
  private myClassInstance = new MyClass();
  myClassInstance.myArr = "hello world";
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with this code. This line: private myClassInstance = new MyClass(); - VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an ideal opportunity for a content provider in my opinion

Take a look here if unfamiliar with them:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Thanks, but i am looking for an easier solution right now. Later i definitely want to learn about content providers.

Comment: I mean i am using a content provider to get the names from the phone book but i dont know if i can use it to pass an array to another class.