# Android passing an array from an activity to a customadapter class

Tags: android, adapter

In MainAcitivty.java i populate an Arraylist with items. I need these items in my customadapter class because i need them to set the colour of certain rows in a textview.

I have a dynamic array: storage [], whose size is set during the process:

```
 storage = new int[db];
```

This array has the following items e.g.: 35,56,67

The arraylist "myArr3" has the same items but type of the elements are string.

This is the definition of the myArr3 arraylist:

```
  ArrayList<String> myArr3 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I am looking for a solution to manages these items in the other class whether it is an integer type array or a string type arraylist.

In MyCustomBaseAdapter2.java i set the layout of the Adapter:

```
package com.bfarago.nevnap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyCustomBaseAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
     private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 public MyCustomBaseAdapter2(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
  searchArrayList = results;
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }

public MyCustomBaseAdapter2(OnClickListener onClickListener,
        ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public int getCount() {
  return searchArrayList.size();
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return searchArrayList.get(position);
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();


       holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.left);
       holder.txtCityState = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.right);


   convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
  holder.txtCityState.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getCityState());



  return convertView;
 }

static class ViewHolder {
  TextView txtName;
  TextView txtCityState;

 }
}
```

Comment: The answer can be found in [this][1] topic.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069694/android-array-as-global-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use intents to pass an array from one activity to another activity.

The answer can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069694/android-array-as-global-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the integer  array to a string `ArrayList` and then use the `ArrayList` in your `Adapter`

You can change your integer array  to string array to  like this

```
 int storage [] = new int[db];
 int stringstorage[] = new String[db];
 for (int i = 0; i < db; i++) {
 stringstorage[i] =storage[i] ;
}
```

Now Change the `stringstorage` to your `ArrayList`

```
  List<String> l = Arrays.asList(stringstorage);
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(l);
```

Now use the `list` as  your need.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: 1. What is difference between your arraylist and mine?

2. How am i supposed to use this arraylist in the other class?

Comment: I am just converting your integer array to a string arraylist.So that you can use it in your `MyCustomBaseAdapter2`.Let me know where is problem you are facing